# Sort by popularity

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 'records' table with two columns "meta_value" and "field_id":

```
meta_value  field_id    item_id
Customer    11      1
Sweden      1       1
Second      1       1
First       1       1
Done        1       2
No      1       2
First1      2       2
First2      2       2
Finland     2       3
Customer    11      3
112233      2       3
Booked      2       3
First NAme  89      4
Last Name   9       4
Belgium     3       4
Customer Name   11      4
11223344    12      5
Booked      3       5
First Name2 89      5
Last Name2  9       5
The Netherlands 10      6
Customer Name2  11      6
221133      4       6
Booked      4       6
```

`Item_id` means id of the form submitted on the website, 
`field_id` - parameter name in the form  
and `meta_value`  - the value of this parameter.

`field_id=1` is the name of the person (value is stored in `meta_value`), `field_id=2` is the keyword (value is stored in `meta_value`), which this person has entered.

What I need to do is to show top-5 persons, who entered "booked" as a keyword the most times.
I'm not very good in MySQL requests, so maybe someone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As this is almost certainly homework (please tag it as such), we need to ask you to show us what you've tried...  We'll help, but we won't do it for you.

Comment: Since you have meta-values, field IDs and form IDs in the data, but nothing about people, it looks as though you've omitted some crucial information from the question.  How do you know which person entered the data with the meta-value 'Booked'?  (Since the data shows 'Booked', presumably that's is what is needed, not 'booked'.  Sadly, computers require such precision and care of detail.)

Comment: Another hint : needs `count` + `group by` also

Comment: ORDER BY and LIMIT are easy, but how can I COUNT "booked" keyword for each person ??

Comment: @Oleg By using group by.

Comment: If you use `select .... count(...), ... where ....group by ... order by .... limit ...` you will reach your answer. See the select syntax [Mysql Select Syntax] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: just perfect... Oleg you will be master one day!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it:

```
SELECT t3.name, COUNT(*) as Cnt FROM 
(SELECT t1.meta_value AS name, t2.meta_value AS type, t2.item_id AS field_id  FROM 
( SELECT * FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=9) AS t1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT * FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=13) AS t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id WHERE t2.meta_value="Booked") AS t3   GROUP BY t3.name ORDER BY Cnt DESC
```